# Collinearity between continuous and categorical variable

Tags: python, collinearity

I have a medical dataset with features age, bmi, sex, gender, # of children, region, charges, smoker. Here smoker, gender, sex and region are categorical variables and others are numerical features. How do I check for collinearity between these in my dataset?

Answer (score 1):

You could just regress against any given variable.

You could also generate a matrix of correlation metrics. Depending on the variable type, you would need a different metric. Here are some common ones:

- **Numeric-Numeric**: [Pearson's Correlation Coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient)

  - For rank correlation, you can use [Spearman's Rank Correlation Coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient)
- **Nominal-Nominal**: [Cramér's V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_V)

  - For two categories, this is equivalent to the [Pearson Phi Coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi_coefficient)
- **Numeric-Nominal**: [t-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Independent_two-sample_t-test) for 2 variables or [ANOVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance) for more than 2

  - You can also just regress against them. For example, logistic regression between age and sex could suffice.